# How to passively overlay a second proxy on a PCA biplot?

Tags: r, pca, vegan

I have palaeo data for 2 proxies (specifically plant macrofossils and testate amoebae) from the same lake core. I have run a PCA on the transformed data for both proxies. I wish to passively plot one proxy over the other on the same biplot in order to investigate how one might be influencing the other.

I am familiar with how to construct a biplot in R using vegan and the plot, points, arrows and text commands etc. My question is if I plot one proxy over the other, is there anything other than ensuring the scaling of the proxies is the same in order for the final plot to be accurate? Is it ok to create a biplot of one proxy and simply overlay the second set of species data as below? Is this what is known as a "passive" overlay?

```
# construct biplot for proxy1
plot(proxy1_pca, type = "n", scaling = 3)
text(proxy1_pca, display = "species", scaling =3)
points(proxy1_pca, display = "sites", scaling = 3)
ordipointlabel(proxy1_pca, display = "sites", , scaling = 3, cex = 0.7, add = TRUE)

# overlay proxy2
text(proxy2_pca, display="species", scaling = 3)
```

Any comments appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can really make an ordination with both macrofossil and testate data. I would make separate ordinations and then run a procrustes analysis or do a co-correspondence analysis

Comment: Thanks for the advice, wasn't sure if it was possible or statistically sound. Co-correspondence analysis sounds like it might be an option, only problem is that both both groups aren't analysed at exactly the same level/depth in all instances. Does this rule out co-corresponsence analysis?

Comment: @steve24 technically yes; the method aims to find patterns of covariance between the two species groups from the same set of samples. In the example you give, if samples aren't always coeval then you will be mixing up coeval covariances and lagged covariances. It causes issues with procrustes too - both assume the same set of samples is measured for the two proxies. If you can subset to a common set of levels that would be best, but not if you end up throwing out a lot of data. What proportion of the levels are the same in the two proxies?

Comment: @RichardTelford You can do this; Canoco calls them supplementary response variables & in vegan we have `predict(object, type = "sp")` to get new species (variable) scores. But these do require the same set of samples. This essentially gives (for PCA), given the directions of maximal variation in proxy A, where we would predict proxy B to be located given the relationships between proxy A and proxy B in the common set of samples. This would be an asymmetric method, treating proxy A as in some way more important than proxy B. Procrustes, cointeria, or co-correspondence analyses wld be better.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that we have both proxies measured on the same set of samples then yes, this is possible and yes this is a "passive" overlay, although that term is usually used to refer to passive samples. In a passive overlay we use either

1. the set of species scores derived from the "active" set to locate new **samples**, the so-called "passive" samples, into the existing ordination space (via a weighted sum or a weighted average of the these scores, with weights being abundances of the species in the new samples), or
2. the set of site/sample scores derived from the "active" set to locate new **species**, again via a weighted sum or weight average.

As you are interested in proxies (these are the variables or species) we need the sites/sample scores from point 2. This could then be done using the `predict()` method for a range of ordination methods, with `type = "sp"`.

In your case we only have those scores for some, or potentially none, of the samples which limits the applicability of this approach.

Second, you would be restricting the way we place the passive proxy scores to be some function of the relationships between proxies and sites in the active proxy set. Richard (in the comments) suggests two approaches which avoid this either by

1. performing separate ordinations and then comparing the degree of association between the resulting configurations (via a procrustes rotation), or,
2. performing a single ordination via co-correspondence analysis which, unlike procrustes or the passive response variable approach you mention, extracts patterns of *covariance* between the the two proxies.

But in both cases there is the assumption that the two proxies have been measured on the same samples (locations, time points). As I mentioned in my comment, if you have some or mostly overlap in the samples where both proxies were analysed you could use the common subset of samples/levels for this analysis.

For the procrustes approach, where you by hand do the separate ordinations and then compare, you could always add in the samples where only one proxy was measured (to the ordination for that proxy) by treating those samples as passive. The Procrustes analysis should only be done using the common set of samples/levels, but you could plot these passive samples post-hoc onto the original analyses.

You can also interpolate one proxy record to the same levels/depths as the first, but that is not advisable as by doing so you remove a lot of the variation from the interpolated series and thus the co-CA or procrustes analysis would be anti-conservative because of the much-reduced noise component in the interpolated proxy series.

Comment: Thanks for the help Gavin and @Richard. This all sounds good. Unfortunately I've checked and the plantmacros and testates are on alternate levels as the entire sample was used for macrofossils. Is interpolating one proxy record to the same level as the first my only option if I want to use any of the approaches above? I've been looking at the timing of change using PCA axis scores plotted along my strat plots but I was hoping to go further and look more robustly at which species are co-occuring. I know other papers have used BIOENV to compare groups but again I've the same problem with levels.

Comment: @steve24 This isn't something one can answer in general - any answer will depend on how much time difference there is between adjacent samples and whether those differences are biologically meaningful. For a co-occurrence question it seems somewhat dubious to not have worked on the same material.

Comment: @steve24 You could think about fitting models to specific species to compare the inferred trends, which is probably what I'd do, but you can't do this for all species for all proxies if you have a large number (for practical reasons just doing the comparisons) or for those species that are only observed a few times. For the most abundant taxa this would be fine. Doing this properly/carefully will require a little effort.

Comment: yes ideally would have liked same samples but unfortunately one of the problems with working on second hand material. Might have to stick with more qualitative comparisons down core. These approaches will be useful for some of my other sites though where the levels match better. 210Pb suggests around 0.3-1.0 cm/y for top quarter but likely much slower accumulation lower down. Maybe side by side biplots is best for a qualitative comparison? and avoids the levels issue. Excuse my basic knowledge of ordination/stats, not strictly a discussion for stack overflow but appreciate the help.